# Multiple domains differen paths marathon lb

Tags: marathon, service-discovery

I would like to hit the same service on two domains with different paths.
Configured in marathon lb.

http://front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos/auth

and

http://auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos

I have tried:

```
HAPROXY_0_VHOST=front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos,auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
HAPROXY_0_PATH=/auth
```

This will let me hit

http://front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos/auth and
http://auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos/auth

Not exactly what I wanted.

I have also tried

```
HAPROXY_0_VHOST=front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos,auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
HAPROXY_0_PATH=/auth
HAPROXY_1_PATH=/
```

That changes nothing.

Two separate VHOST labels does not work either

```
HAPROXY_0_VHOST=front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
HAPROXY_1_VHOST=auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
HAPROXY_0_PATH=/auth
HAPROXY_1_PATH=/
```

1_VHOST and 1_PATH is ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic you're looking for doesn't quite exist in MLB. It sounds like you want something like:

```
if (vhostA) use backend
else if (vhostB && pathB) use backend
```

There's a trick to accomplish the code above. If you look at the generated config, you should see a set of ACLs in the frontends for HTTP and HTTPS. To get rid of the extraneous config, configure *just* a vhost and switch to the simpler [`HAPROXY_HTTP_FRONTEND_ACL`](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/Longhelp.md#haproxy_http_frontend_acl). We need to override the defaults, like this:

```
{
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_0_HTTP_FRONTEND_ACL"="  acl path_is_auth path_beg /auth\n  acl host_is_front_dev hdr(host) -i front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos\n  acl host_is_auth_dev hdr(host) -i auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos\n  use_backend {backend} if host_is_auth_dev or host_is_front_dev path_is_auth\n"
  }
}
```

That should do it. Check the generated HAProxy config from MLB with `curl marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:9090/_haproxy_getconfig`.

You'll also need to update the equivalent HTTPS frontend ACLs if you're using HTTPS. [Look here for a full list of the templates](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/Longhelp.md).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the `{n}` index in the labels refers to the `servicePort` index of the service itself.

So, for the separate VHOST labels to work, you must create an additional port mapping and port definition to the service (for a total of two sets).

for example

```
"portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": 80,
      "hostPort": 0,
      "servicePort": 10010,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    },
    {
      "containerPort": 80,
      "hostPort": 0,
      "servicePort": 10011,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
```

and

```
"portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10010,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    },
    {
      "port": 10011,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
]
```

Then, you can add the labels to the service as you were intending

```
HAPROXY_0_VHOST=front-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
HAPROXY_0_PATH=/auth
HAPROXY_0_HTTP_BACKEND_PROXYPASS_PATH=/auth
HAPROXY_1_VHOST=auth-dev.marathon.ice.mesos
```

... the `HAPROXY_1_PATH=/` label is not necessary ;-)

If you're using the `HAPROXY_{n}_PATH` label, you will surely need to set an additional label `HAPROXY_{n}_HTTP_BACKEND_PROXYPASS_PATH` to map the path (in our example, `/auth`) to the root level of your app (In our example, `/`)

Of course check the HA-Proxy config at

```
curl marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:9090/_haproxy_getconfig
```

As [Brenden Mathews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4488486/brenden-matthews) said ;-)